# Size of pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, pthreads, circular-buffer

So, I have this structure used to implement a circular buffer of another structure (`plane`)

```
typedef struct queue
{
    struct plane *q;        
    int size, capacity, front, rear;  
}queue;
```

After this I declare the structure

```
queue *q;
```

and later, to inicialize the buffer, I use this method

```
int queue_init(int size){

    q = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue));

    q->q=malloc(sizeof(struct plane) * size); 

    q->size = 0;
    q->capacity = size;
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

which is supposed to be the one that inicializes all the variables I need to use the buffer and the buffer itself with `q->q=malloc(sizeof(struct plane) * size);`. 
The problem is the size of the buffer is always 8 bytes, where it should be as it says, `size` times the size of `plane`, which is actually 16.
The thing is how should I initialize the variables so I can get the buffer the size I want. I can't change the return value or the parameters of the function as limitations. 
Thank you beforehand!

Comment: "he problem is the size of the buffer is always 8 bytes" How do you know? This looks fine to me. Well, except the function never returning the malloc'ed pointer but using globals instead...

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in comments but [edit] your question and put them _there_.

Comment: When you say you declare things, you are actually declaring pointers to things. I suspect you are seeing the size of the pointer, not the size of the thing pointed to. You can write `sizeof *q` to get the size of the default object q points to.

Comment: Proper naming is always a good idea. E.g. `struct plane *q;` should rather be named `struct plane *planequeue; `. This would avoid horrors like `q->q`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the size of the array by doing `sizeof(q->q)`, this won't work as you expect.

Since the `q` field of `struct queue` is a pointer and not an array, `sizeof(q->q)` actually gives you the size of the pointer which on your machine appears to be 8 bytes in size.

The language doesn't keep track of how much memory was allocated in a call to `malloc`, so you need to keep track of that yourself.  The good thing is that   you're already doing that.

You correctly allocated room for an array of `struct place` of size `size` by using `malloc(sizeof(struct plane) * size)`, and you stored `size` in `q->capacity`.  So you know how big the array is.